# Unable to load datasets from datacube using x,y, lat,lon or geopolygon

Tags: open-data-cube

I get an empty array if I load the Landsat 8 dataset using x,y, lat,lon or geopolygon.

```
ds = dc.load(product='ls8_usgs_sr_scene',
          time="2014-01-26",
          geopolygon=geom,
          output_crs="EPSG:4326", 
          resolution=(-0.00027,0.00027))
```

However, I'm able to load the dataset if those parameters are omitted, but that means I had to load the entire scene.

Is it something missing from the product definition or the metadata?

Comment: Are you sure there's data at that location? Also, what does your `geom` object look like?

Also, this is a Digital Earth Africa question, so it's implementation specific...